# Clicking a text is not expanding table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problem in my JS code. I tried much but was unable to solve it. The problem is that i have a dashboard which have multiple pages. We can switch from one page to another without reloading the page.
Code of switching the pages without refresh

```
  $(sidebar_a).click(function (e) {
        // load another page without reloading

    if ($(sidebar_a).hasClass("active")) {
      $(sidebar_a).removeClass("active");
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass("active");
    setTimeout(() => {
      let url = $(this).attr("data-href");
      // show page content and change the url
      $(".recent-orders").load(url + " .recent-orders", function () {
        window.history.replaceState(null, null, url);
      });
    }, 500);
    $(".recent-orders").load("./inc/preloader.html");
  });
```

I have multiple pages which includes dashboard orders customers etc. Each page has table which loads when we switch from one page to another. I have limited the tbody with 4 customers. If user wants to see all the customers he have to press show all button As shown in picture [See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmHDn.png)

Table doesnot expand on pressing show all button if we switch between pages . If we switch to another page we have to reload the page than show-all button works well. And after reloading if we switch to another page as I told without reloading and come back to previous it doesnot work neither on previous page nor on next page.Each page contain table as shown above in picture with show-all button. Each time I have to reload page if I switch from one page to another. I want to solve it and make it work without reloading page.
Here is My Both Pages code between which I am switching.
**1st** Page

```
<div class="recent-orders">
    <h2>Recent Orders</h2>
    <table id="recent-orders-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Product Number</th>
                <th>Payment</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>iPhone 12</td>
                <td>0002</td>
                <td>Due</td>
                <td class="warning">Pending</td>

                <!-- Classes available for status text color warning,success,danger,primary -->
                <a href="./index?detail_customer=">
                    <td class="primary"> <a href="./index?detail_customer="> Details </a> </td>
                </a>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>iPhone 12</td>
                <td>0003</td>
                <td>Due</td>
                <td class="warning">Pending</td>

                <!-- Classes available for status text color warning,success,danger,primary -->
                <a href="./index?detail_customer=">
                    <td class="primary"> <a href="./index?detail_customer="> Details </a> </td>
                </a>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Apple Tab</td>
                <td>0004</td>
                <td>Due</td>
                <td class="warning">Pending</td>

                <!-- Classes available for status text color warning,success,danger,primary -->
                <a href="./index?detail_customer=">
                    <td class="primary"> <a href="./index?detail_customer="> Details </a> </td>
                </a>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>iPhone 12</td>
                <td>0001</td>
                <td>Due</td>
                <td class="warning">Pending</td>

                <!-- Classes available for status text color warning,success,danger,primary -->
                <a href="./index?detail_customer=">
                    <td class="primary"> <a href="./index?detail_customer="> Details </a> </td>
                </a>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="hidetbody">
            <tr>
                <td>iPhone 2</td>
                <td>0003</td>
                <td>Due</td>
                <td class="warning">Pending</td>

                <!-- Classes available for status text color warning,success,danger,primary -->
                <a href="./index?detail_customer=">
                    <td class="primary"> <a href="./index?detail_customer="> Details </a> </td>
                </a>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>iPhone 12</td>
                <td>0003</td>
                <td>Due</td>
                <td class="warning">Pending</td>

                <!-- Classes available for status text color warning,success,danger,primary -->
                <a href="./index?detail_customer=">
                    <td class="primary"> <a href="./index?detail_customer="> Details </a> </td>
                </a>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Apple Tab</td>
                <td>0004</td>
                <td>Due</td>
                <td class="warning">Pending</td>

                <!-- Classes available for status text color warning,success,danger,primary -->
                <a href="./index?detail_customer=">
                    <td class="primary"> <a href="./index?detail_customer="> Details </a> </td>
                </a>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>iPhone 12</td>
                <td>0001</td>
                <td>Due</td>
                <td class="warning">Pending</td>

                <!-- Classes available for status text color warning,success,danger,primary -->
                <a href="./index?detail_customer=">
                    <td class="primary"> <a href="./index?detail_customer="> Details </a> </td>
                </a>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="show-all-text">Show All</a>
</div>
```

**2nd** Page

```
<div class="recent-orders">
    <h2>Customers</h2>
    <table id="recent-orders-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Customer Id</th>
                <th>Customer Name</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>UZAIR</td>
                <td>Lahore</td>
                <td class="success">03233337187</td>

                <!-- Classes available for status text color warning,success,danger,primary -->

                <td class="primary"> <a class="detail_c_each" href="./index?detail_customer=31"> Details </a> </td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>UZAIR</td>
                <td>Lahore</td>
                <td class="success">03233337187</td>

                <!-- Classes available for status text color warning,success,danger,primary -->
                <td class="primary"> <a class="detail_c_each" href="./index?detail_customer=31"> Details </a> </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>UZAIR</td>
                <td>Lahore</td>
                <td class="success">03233337187</td>

                <!-- Classes available for status text color warning,success,danger,primary -->
                <td class="primary"> <a class="detail_c_each" href="./index?detail_customer=32"> Details </a> </td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>
        <tbody class="hidetbody">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>UZAIR</td>
                <td>Lahore</td>
                <td class="success">03233337187</td>

                <!-- Classes available for status text color warning,success,danger,primary -->

                <td class="primary"> <a class="detail_c_each" href="./index?detail_customer=31"> Details </a> </td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>UZAIR</td>
                <td>Lahore</td>
                <td class="success">03233337187</td>

                <!-- Classes available for status text color warning,success,danger,primary -->
                <td class="primary"> <a class="detail_c_each" href="./index?detail_customer=31"> Details </a> </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>UZAIR</td>
                <td>Lahore</td>
                <td class="success">03233337187</td>

                <!-- Classes available for status text color warning,success,danger,primary -->
                <td class="primary"> <a class="detail_c_each" href="./index?detail_customer=32"> Details </a> </td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="show-all-text">Show All</a>
</div>
```

**My All JS Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  let sideMenu = document.querySelector("aside");
  let menuBtn = document.querySelector("#menu-btn");
  let closeBtn = document.querySelector("#close-btn");
  let themeToggler = document.querySelector(".theme-toggler");
  let detailCustomerEach = document.querySelectorAll(".detail_c_each");
  let sidebar_a = document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar_a");
  let alerts = document.querySelectorAll(".alert");

  // hide  alerts
  $(".alert-success").hide();
  $(".alert-danger").hide();

  $(".hidetbody").hide();

  // show .hidetr when click on show-all

  $(".show-all-text").click(function () {
    $(".hidetbody").show();

    // toggle the text of #show-all
    $(".show-all-text").text(function (i, text) {
      return text === "Show All" ? "Hide" : "Show All";
    });

    // toggle class of .hidetr
    $(".hidetbody").toggleClass("show-all");
    // if tbody has class show-all than show all tr
    if ($("tbody").hasClass("show-all")) {
      $(".hidetbody").show();
    } else {
      $(".hidetbody").hide();
    }
  });

  // slide the menu for mobile
  $(menuBtn).click(function () {
    sideMenu.style.display = "block";
    $(sideMenu).removeClass("animate__animated animate__slideOutLeft");
    $(sideMenu).addClass("animate__animated animate__slideInLeft");
  });

  $(sidebar_a).click(function (e) {
    // load another page without reloading

    if ($(sidebar_a).hasClass("active")) {
      $(sidebar_a).removeClass("active");
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass("active");
    setTimeout(() => {
      let url = $(this).attr("data-href");
      // show page content and change the url
      $(".recent-orders").load(url + " .recent-orders", function () {
        window.history.replaceState(null, null, url);
      });
    }, 500);
    $(".recent-orders").load("./inc/preloader.html");
  });

  $("form").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var formData = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: form.attr("action"),
      data: formData,
      success: function (data) {
        $(".alert-success").show();
        // hide alerts after 3 seconds

        $(".alert-success").fadeOut(3000);
      },
      error: function (data) {
        $(".alert-danger").show();
      },
    });
  });

  // close the menu for mobile
  $(closeBtn).click(function () {
    // sideMenu.style.display = "none";
    $(sideMenu).removeClass("animate__animated animate__slideInLeft");
    $(sideMenu).addClass("animate__animated animate__slideOutLeft");
  });

  $(".add-product").click(function () {
    window.open("./index", "_self");
  });

  // change theme
  $(themeToggler).click(function () {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme-variables");
    themeToggler.querySelector("span:nth-child(1)").classList.toggle("active");
    themeToggler.querySelector("span:nth-child(2)").classList.toggle("active");
  });
});
```

And I more point is that all the files are included through php file by passing parameter in url and by using $_GET in php to include files.

**index**.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.sandbox.google.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Sharp" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>

<script>
let sales = document.getElementsByClassName("sales");
let expenses = document.getElementsByClassName("expenses");
let income = document.getElementsByClassName("income");

function fadeCards() {
    $(sales).addClass("animate__animated animate__zoomIn");
    $(expenses).addClass("animate__animated animate__zoomIn");
    $(income).addClass("animate__animated animate__zoomIn");
}
</script>


<body onload="fadeCards();">

    <div class="container">
        <!-- START OF LEFT SIDEBAR -->

        <?php
        include('inc/left_sidebar.php');
        ?>

        <!-- END OF LEFT SIDEBAR -->

        <!-- Main Section Start -->

        <?php
        include('inc/main.php');
        ?>

        <!-- Main Section End -->

        <!-- START OF RIGHT SIDEBAR -->

        <?php
        include('inc/right_sidebar.php');
        ?>

        <!-- END OF RIGHT SIDEBAR -->

    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

**main**.php in which all files are included by passing paramter in url:

```
<main>
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <div class="date">
        <input type="date" name="" id="">
    </div>
    <div class="insights">
        <div class="sales">
            <span class="material-symbols-sharp">
                analytics
            </span>
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="left">
                    <h3>Total Sales</h3>
                    <h1>$250000</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="progress">
                    <svg>
                        <circle cx="38" cy="38" r="36">
                        </circle>
                    </svg>
                    <div class="number">
                        <p>80%</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">Last 24 Hours</small>
            <!-- End Of Sales -->
        </div>
        <div class="expenses">
            <span class="material-symbols-sharp">
                bar_chart
            </span>
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="left">
                    <h3>Total Expenses</h3>
                    <h1>$250000</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="progress">
                    <svg>
                        <circle cx="38" cy="38" r="36">
                        </circle>
                    </svg>
                    <div class="number">
                        <p>62%</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">Last 24 Hours</small>
            <!-- End Of Expenses -->
        </div>
        <div class="income">
            <span class="material-symbols-sharp">
                stacked_line_chart
            </span>
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="left">
                    <h3>Total Income</h3>
                    <h1>$4840</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="progress">
                    <svg>
                        <circle cx="38" cy="38" r="36">
                        </circle>
                    </svg>
                    <div class="number">
                        <p>44%</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">Last 24 Hours</small>
            <!-- End Of Expenses -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['dashboard'])) {
        include "dashboard.php";
    }
    if (isset($_GET['customers'])) {
        include "customers.php";
    }
    if (isset($_GET['detail_customer'])) {
        include "detail_customer.php";
    }
    ?>
</main>
```

Comment: `let sidebar_a = document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar_a");` collects only elements present at the time the code is run. You've to delegate the event on the closest static ancestor element, ex. on the parent element of `.recent-orders`, something like  `let wrapper = document.querySelector(".recent-orders").parentElement;`, and attach the event: `$(wrapper).on('click', '.sidebar_a', function (e) {...});`.

Comment: Still Not Working

Comment: .recent-orders is the parent element of all the pages. As i already told you each page has a table and each table has a class .recent-orders on all the pages.

Comment: And I more point is that all the files are included through php file by passing parameter in url and by using $_GET in php to include files. I have edit the code above for main index page

Comment: ??? `$(".recent-orders").load(...);` loads new content to `.recent-orders`, what ever is coming in, new elements are created. "_[.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/#load-url-data-complete) sets the HTML contents of the matched elements to the returned data_".

Comment: So what should we take next step to make it perfect.

Comment: I've already explained it in my first comment. Only that you don't need `.parentElement` if `.recent-orders` is the parent element. I'm not sure why you're calling `$(".recent-orders").load` twice, that probably is an issue.

Comment: I am calling it twice because I want to show preloader for .5 sec as you can see in 2nd load that its loading preloader and then main content